# Вызов функции в R

Tags: r

Как можно сохранить собственную функцию и потом ее вызвать в другом скрипте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю есть как минимум 2 способа

1. Сохранить как R файл и вызывать как `source('путь до файла.R')`
2. Сделать отдельный пакет описание на [Rstudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486488-Developing-Packages-with-RStudio)